# Remove spaces in group of numbers just after a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove spaces between numbers immediately following a string (`po box` in this case).

I can acheive this using `re.match` and some replace logic, but it sure would be prettier if i could do this with a conditional `re.sub`.

How can i integrate a capture group into a regex sub?

I've tried many different versions of the code immediately below, but to no avail:

```py
my_string = "po box 12 34 5 heisenburg 902 rr 15"
re.sub(r'(?:po box)([0-9 ]+)', r'', my_string)
```

Expected results:

```
po box 12 59 76           => po box 125976
po box 56 56 barry 56 87  => po box 5656 barry 56 87
barry box 56 87           => barry box 56 87
```

I've put this together that has the desired effect, but is not ideal.

```py
my_string = "po box 12 34 5 heisenburg 902 rr 15"
match = re.match(r'po box([0-9 ]+)', my_string)

if match:
    # remove spaces between numbers
    spaceless_numbers = match.group(1).replace(' ', '')

    # get original string positions
    start = match.span(1)[0]
    end = match.span(1)[1]

    # get start and end portions of the original string
    first_part = my_string[:start]
    second_part = my_string[end:]
    
    # concatenate start + spaces removed section + end
    print('{} {} {}'.format(first_part, spaceless_numbers, second_part).strip())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
my_strings = ["po box 12 34 5 heisenburg 902 rr 15", "po box 12 59 76","po box 56 56 barry 56 87","barry box 56 87"]
p = re.compile(r'\b(po\s+box\s*)(\d+(?:\s+\d+)+)')
for s in my_strings:
  print(s, ' => ', p.sub(lambda x: f"{x.group(1)}{''.join(c for c in x.group(2).split())}", s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1MCLNq). Output:

```py
po box 12 34 5 heisenburg 902 rr 15  =>  po box 12345 heisenburg 902 rr 15
po box 12 59 76  =>  po box 125976
po box 56 56 barry 56 87  =>  po box 5656 barry 56 87
barry box 56 87  =>  barry box 56 87
```

The regex is

```py
\b(po\s+box\s*)(\d+(?:\s+\d+)+)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6HfPc1/1). Details:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(po\s+box\s*)` - Group 1: `po`, 1+ whitespaces, `box`, 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:\s+\d+)+)` - Group 2: 1+ digits and one or more occurrences of 1+ whitespaces and 1+ digits

The `f"{x.group(1)}{''.join(c for c in x.group(2).split())}"` replacement is a concatenation of Group 1 and Group 2 with all whitespace removed.